# Нужна помощь, бот должен угадывать число, нужно реализовать это через бинарный поиск числа

Tags: python

Вот мой код:

```
import requests

import random

reqUser = input('давайте сыграем в игру угадай число!? \ny-да ')
if reqUser.upper() == 'Y':
    print('начинаем играть')
    result = requests.get('https://game.aleksserg.repl.co/gnum')
    gameHash = result.json()['answer']
    print('игра началась. Робот загадал число. от 0 до 1 000 000')

    print('запускаем бота для поиска загаданного числа! ')
    maxNum = 1000000
    minNum = 0

    while True:



        numBot = random.randint(minNum,maxNum)
        print(f'пробуем число {numBot}')
        result = requests.get(f'https://game.aleksserg.repl.co/gnum/{gameHash}/{numBot}')
        result = result.json()['answer']
        if result == 'Larger':
            print('не угадали! Мое число БОЛЬШЕ!')
            minNum = numBot
        elif result == 'Less':
            print('не угадали! Мое число МЕНЬШЕ!')
            maxNum = numBot
        elif result == 'Victory!':
            print('Бот нашел число!!!!')
            print(f'число было: {numBot}')
            break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `numBot = random.randint(minNum,maxNum)` используйте `numBot = (minNum + maxNum) / 2`.
Также стоит сделать проверку на то, что юзер вас "обманывает".

```py
numBot = (minNum + maxNum) / 2
result = requests.get(f'https://game.aleksserg.repl.co/gnum/{gameHash}/{numBot}')
result = result.json()['answer']
if result == 'Victory!':
    print('Бот нашел число!!!!')
    print(f'число было: {numBot}')
    break
elif maxNum == minNum:
    print('Обманщик!')
elif result == 'Larger':
    print('не угадали! Мое число БОЛЬШЕ!')
    minNum = numBot
elif result == 'Less':
    print('не угадали! Мое число МЕНЬШЕ!')
    maxNum = numBot
```